# Login Servlet not responding

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a basic login system in JSP using session API. I think my code is just fine, still when I am running the system in tomcat (Eclipse), after filling the form, the servlet loads and doesn't respond at all (no output).

This is my **login.jsp:**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="loginservlet" method="post">
    <h1>Please Login</h1>
    Login:    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type=submit value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my **loginservlet:**

```
package connectm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class loginservlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         response.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Connection conn = null;
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
          String dbName = "test";
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
          String userName = "root"; 
          String password = "root";
           String username="";
           String userpass="";
           String strQuery=""; 
          Statement st=null;
          ResultSet rs=null;
          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName,
                        password);
                if (request.getParameter("username") != null
                        && request.getParameter("username") != ""
                        && request.getParameter("password") != null
                        && request.getParameter("password") != "") {
                    username = request.getParameter("username").toString();
                    userpass = request.getParameter("password").toString();
                    /*strQuery = "select * from user where username='" + username
                            + "' and  password='" + userpass + "'";*/
                    //System.out.println(strQuery);
                    strQuery = "select username from user where username= ? and password= ?";
                    st = conn.createStatement();
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
                    ps.setString(1, username);
                    ps.setString(2, userpass);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery(strQuery);
                    int count = 0;
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        session.setAttribute("username", rs.getString(1));
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count > 0) {
                        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
                    } else {
                        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
                    }
                } else {
                    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
                }
                out.println("Connected to the database");
                conn.close();
                out.println("Disconnected from database");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }




    }

}
```

I am really clueless as to what's going wrong and where. I would really appreciate if someone could point out the error/mistake please.

Answer (score 2):

Here,

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

you're totally swallowing and ignoring the exception. If an exception is been thrown, you will indeed get a blank page this way. Finish the `TODO`. **Handle** the exception. E.g.

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("Login failed", e);
    }
```

Then you'll get a nice server default HTTP 500 error page with the complete stacktrace which contains all detail about the cause of the problem, which should be self-explaining enough. For example a `ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` which indicate that you didn't put the JDBC driver in the classpath, or a `SQLException: no suitable driver` which indicate that the JDBC connection URL is wrong, etcetera.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should not write to the response body using `out.println("Connected to the database");` and so on while you're controlling the request/response in a servlet. Rather use `System.out.println()` or a logger.

Comment: @BalusC I did both the things as you pointed out. The stacktrace helped and the problem is of `ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. But very strange as I had put the jar file of mysql driver in the build path of project and was working fine before (eclipse) :|

Comment: The JAR needs to be placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder which is by default part of webapp's runtime classpath. You don't need to do anything else. Eclipse will take care about setting the build path right automatically when you use `/WEB-INF/lib` the right way. So you first need to undo all manual changes/settings in the build path.

Comment: @BaluC Did as you said and put the mysql connector in the lib folder but still the same error :|

Comment: Then it was the wrong JAR file or you did not properly rebuild/redeploy/restart the project/webapp/server.

Comment: @BaluC As it turned out, the MySql connector jar has also to be placed in `common/lib` folder of Tomcat to make it work. Worked anyhow. Thanks

Comment: This is only mandatory if you're getting the connection from a container managed `DataSource`. The code in your question didn't give that away. So if you was really running the code as in your question and dropping the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` didn't work, then your web project settings/buildpath is probably totally messed up. Consider recreating a new *Dynamic Web Project*. Eclipse will then prepare the right project folder structure including the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and the right buildpath settings.

Comment: for my project I implemented something similar and then moved to a custom authentication on Resin with FormLogin and  a AbstractAuthentication implementation because there was no encryption and I found out that the userName and password are naked in the URL which is worst. Is there any disadvantage of using a servlet for managing login?